there is a subspace $T$ of $V$ for which $V=S_i⊕ T $ for all $i=1,...,k$. In other words, $T $ is a common complement of the subspaces $S_i$.
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over an infinite field $F$. Prove that if $S_1,...,S_k $ are subspaces of $V$ of equal dimension then there is a subspace $T$ of $V$ for which $V=S_i⊕ T $ for all $i=1,...,k$. In other words, $T $ is a common complement of the subspaces $S_i$.
I found some ways (in this site and in another places) to solve that but I can't understand exactly how they works.
One of these ways is:

Step 1: For each subspace $S_i$ extend its basis $B_i$ to a basis $B_{v_i}$
of the entire space $V$.
Step 2: Determine the intersection of all the extended bases $B_t= B_{v_1} \cap ...\cap B_{v_k}$. The intersection should contain $dim(V)-n $ vectors.
Step 3: Construct the subspace $T$ as the span of the intersection of bases $T=Span(B_t)$, and verify that it forms a direct sum with each subspace $S_i$ and satisfies the Dimension Theorem. This confirms $T$ as a common complement of the subspaces $S_i$.

My problem here is in the step 2. How we know that this intersection have $ dim(V)-n$ vector. I see that it maybe be empty set.
For example: In $\mathbb R^2 $ Let $S_1= span \{(0,1)\}, S_2=span \{(1,2)\}, B_{v_1}=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}, B_{v_2}=\{(1,2),(3,1)\} $ So $B_t= \emptyset$

Way:


We can use downward induction on $\dim V_i$.
The case $\dim V_i=n$ is trivial (with $S=\{0\}$). Now suppose $\dim V_i<n$, then we have
$\bigcup_iV_i\ne V$, so there is an $s\in V$ such that $s\notin \bigcup_iV_i$.
Then apply the induction hypothesis on $V_i\oplus\Bbb F s$.

I can't understand what will be the induction hypothesis here?

That first "proof" is nonsense, for the reasons you cite.

Indeed the first proof you gave makes no sense to me either.
As for the second way, you want to prove the following by backwards induction for all $0\leq j\leq n$: $P(j)$:"For any $S_1,...,S_k$ subspaces of $V$ with $\text{dim}(S_i) = j$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$, there exists a subspace $T$ of $V$ such that $V = S_i\oplus T$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$".
As you stated, the case $j = n$ is trivial as $T = \{0\}$ suffices. Now suppose $1\leq j \leq n$ is such that $P(j)$ is true, and let $S_1,...,S_k$ subspaces of $V$ with $\text{dim}(S_i) = j-1$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$. Take $s\in V \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^kS_i$ and apply $P(j)$ to the subspaces $S'_i := S_i \oplus \mathbb Fs$, all of dimension $j$. There exists $T'$ a subspace of $V$ such that $V = T'\oplus S'_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$. Thus pick $T = T'\oplus \mathbb Fs$, and we do have that $V = T\oplus S_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$. Thus we have proved $P(j-1)$ as $S_1,...,S_k$ were arbitrary.
Conclusion: $P(j)$ is true for all $0\leq j\leq n$ by the principle of backwards induction.

As in your last post I suggest making use of polynomials.  It is enough to prove this when $V = \mathbb F^n$ and induct on $k$.
Base Case: $k=2$
$S_1$ and $S_2$ have respective bases $\mathbf B^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf B^{(2)}$ which can be extended to bases for $V$ as $\mathbf B_1= \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c} \mathbf B^{(1)} & \mathbf X\end{array}\bigg]$ and $\mathbf B_2= \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c} \mathbf B^{(2)} & \mathbf Y\end{array}\bigg]$.  Then consider $\mathbf B_i(t) =\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c} \mathbf B^{(i)} & t\cdot \mathbf X + (1-t)\cdot\mathbf Y\end{array}\bigg]$.  And $\det\Big(\mathbf B_i(t)\Big)$ is a degree at most $n$ polynomial in $t$ that is not the zero polynomial (check at 0 and 1) hence there are at most $n$ roots$\implies \phi\left(\Big\{\det\big(\mathbf B_1(t)\big), \det\big(\mathbf B_2(t)\big)\Big\}\right)\subseteq \mathbb F -\big\{0\big\}$ where substitution map $\phi:\mathbb F[t]\rightarrow \mathbb F $ given by $\phi(a) = a$ for $a\in \mathbb F$ and $\phi(t)$ is some well chosen value $\in \mathbb F$ (try say $2n+1$ different values)
Inductive Case: $k=K$
$S_r$ for $1\leq r\leq K-1$ have a common complement $\mathbf X$ per induction hypothesis, with bases for $V$ written as $\mathbf B_r= \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c} \mathbf B^{(r)} & \mathbf X\end{array}\bigg]$ and we may augment the basis for $S_K$ to form a basis for $V$ as in $\mathbf B_K= \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c} \mathbf B^{(K)} & \mathbf Y\end{array}\bigg]$.  Then consider $\mathbf B_i(t) =\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c} \mathbf B^{(i)} & t\cdot \mathbf X + (1-t)\cdot\mathbf Y\end{array}\bigg]$.  As before $\det\Big(\mathbf B_i(t)\Big)$ is a degree at most $n$ polynomial in $t$ that is not the zero polynomial (check at 0 and 1) so there will be finitely many roots  $\implies \phi\left(\Big\{\det\big(\mathbf B_1(t)\big), \dots, \det\big(\mathbf B_{K}(t)\big)\Big\}\right)\subseteq \mathbb F -\big\{0\big\}$ again with $\phi: t\mapsto \mathbb F$ for some well chosen value in $\mathbb F$.
